# AWS Secrets Manager - boto3 can't get the secret value

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-secrets-manager

Im not able to get my SecretsManager secret value on a python celery task
I call an endpoint in my REST api that runs a view, that calls a task, and then return a confirmation

```
def authenticate_view(authCode):
    get_token.delay(authCode)
    return HttpResponse('New Token created')
```

After that,  I set up the boto3 client with:

```
client_secrets = boto3.client('secretsmanager')
```

Then I try to get the secret value with the following code:

```
@shared_task(name="get_token")
def get_token():
    try:
        get_secret_value_response = client_secrets.get_secret_value(
            SecretId=secret_name
        )
        database_secrets = json.loads(response['SecretString'])

        print(database_secrets['password'])
    except ClientError as e:
        # For a list of exceptions thrown, see
        # https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_GetSecretValue.html
        raise e
```

This throws me an error `No region provided`
So I tried:

```
client_secrets = boto3.client('secretsmanager', region_name="us-east-1")
```

This gives me an infinite loading when I hit the endpoint that runs the get_token task
I also followed the AWS python3 sample code to SecretsManager, which also gives me an infinite loading

```
def get_secret():

secret_name = "secret_name"
region_name = "us-east-1"

# Create a Secrets Manager client
session = boto3.session.Session()
client = session.client(
    service_name='secretsmanager',
    region_name=region_name
)

try:
    get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(
        SecretId=secret_name
    )
except ClientError as e:
    # For a list of exceptions thrown, see
    # https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_GetSecretValue.html
    raise e

# Decrypts secret using the associated KMS key.
secret = get_secret_value_response['SecretString']

# Your code goes here.
```

I configured my aws data with `aws configure`

The IAM user has the following permissions:

```
AdministratorAccess, SecretsManagerReadWrite
```

What could possible be happening?

Comment: Is this code running in a lambda ? Is that lambda in a VPC ? With a NAT Gateway ?

Comment: @AntoninRiche it is running on a ec2, when I wrote the code in a view instead of a task it worked, still dont know why

Answer (score 0):

You have to define region:

```
secret_name = "My-secret-name"
region_name = "us-east-2"

# Create a Secrets Manager client
session = boto3.session.Session()
client = session.client(
    service_name='secretsmanager',
    region_name=region_name
 )
```